# Adding many items to a list

Tags: list

What is the proper way to add many items to a list?  I assume just using many `add-to-list`s is not the normal way?

Comment: The question is not very clear. In what form are you given the items to begin with? Are they already in some (other) list? or vector? What do you mean by "*proper*" - what are you expecting/preferring? What are your concerns about the different ways of adding items to a list? Do you care whether the list is the value of a global variable, and you want to be sure the variable's value is updated? Do other lists share list structure with the list?

Answer (score 7):

There are many different ways. Not sure if there's a particularly "proper" way. There are considerations you should take depending on how you want to add it (destructively, non-destructively) or if you care a lot about efficiency.

original list
`(1)`
things you want to add
`(2 3 4)`

There are many different ways of adding. Things can be added destructively, meaning the original set of numbers is modified or non-destructively, just generating a new list. To see more look at [list modification](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ListModification).

This is non-destructive.
`(append '(1) '(2 3 4)) ;=> '(1 2 3 4)`

This is destructive and more indirect (more of a replacement than addition), here it replaces the last element of the list `2` with `2 3 4`. Which has the net effect of adding to the list.

If your list is in a variable: `(setq my-list '(1 2))`

`(setcdr my-list '(2 3 4)) ;=> '(2 3 4)`

`my-list ;=> '(1 2 3 4)`.

You could also just do a loop with `add-to-list` or `cons`. Note I'm assuming you don't care about order.

`(dolist (thing things) (add-to-list 'list-var thing))`

`(dolist (thing things) (cons thing list-var))`

I usually use the `append` as it is short to write and more direct. It also is probably among the fastest because it is written in C code whereas `add-to-list` is in elisp.

Comment: `append` is only efficient if all additional elements are already contained in a list and that list is added. It is inefficient for adding many elements sequentially or in small hunks at the tail since in this case its cost grows quadratically with the number of list entries. Note that I have confirmed that fact by timing.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to add many items to a list is *consing* in a loop.

If `l` is the list variable you add an item `i` by

```el
(setq l (cons i l))
```

for which you can use the shorthand

```
(push i l)
```

The computational cost of this operation is independent of the length of the list `l`.

After collecting the items in this way they are in reverse order.
If it is important to retain the order you can call

```el
(setq l (nreverse l))
```

as the last action or just return `(nreverse l)`.
The cost of `nreverse` grows just linearly with the length of the list.

The costs of adding all elements with `add-to-list` grow quadratically with the length of the list (even without `append` set to `t`).

If you want to add an item to a list only if it is not already present. You have to search for that item. In that case you could consider using a hashmap [(search the elisp info files for `make-hash-table`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Hash.html#Creating-Hash) or a sorted list to reduce the computational costs. Note that a single hash access is costly but the read/write access time is essentially independent on the number of elements in the hash.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this question lacks an actual practical example that a person can copy-paste into their config, so here it is:

```el
(defun merge-list-to-list (dst src)
  "Merges content of the 2nd list with the 1st one"
  (set dst
       (append (eval dst) src)))
```

It combines the non-destructive `append` function that merges two lists, and a destructive `set`.

Now, let's say your config had this code:

```el
(add-to-list 'company-dabbrev-code-modes 'c++-mode)
(add-to-list 'company-dabbrev-code-modes 'c-mode)
(add-to-list 'company-dabbrev-code-modes 'php-mode)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mzn\\'"      . minizinc-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.glade$\\'"   . xml-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\PKGBUILD\\'"  . sh-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.service\\'"  . conf-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m$"          . octave-mode))
```

You replace it with this:

```el
(merge-list-to-list 'company-dabbrev-code-modes
                    '(c++-mode c-mode php-mode))

(merge-list-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
                    '(("\\.mzn\\'"      . minizinc-mode)
                      ("\\.glade$\\'"   . xml-mode)
                      ("\\PKGBUILD\\'"  . sh-mode)
                      ("\\.service\\'"  . conf-mode)
                      ("\\.m$"          . octave-mode)))
```

Comment: The purported analogy to `add-to-list` is misleading, as the most notable feature of `add-to-list` is that it *doesn't* add an item which already exists in the list.  If you want `append` you should just use `append`, rather than wrapping that with a name that doesn't behave the way one would expect.

Comment: @phils `append` doesn't mutate original list though. Regarding the analogy: I honestly didn't even know `add-to-list` checks for duplicates. I would disagree calling it a "notable feature", because you would only know that from the docs or someone else. It is actually misleading, because the name of the function says nothing at all about removing dups. So in this case it's `add-to-list` that is misnamed and not the `add-list-to-list`. With that said, I can rename it if you think it would confuse old-timers. Perhaps, `add-list-to-list-allow-dups`…?

Comment: "you would only know that from the docs" -- I don't think that's much of a problem unless you're in the habit of using unfamiliar elisp functions without even reading their docstrings (which I would consider fairly inexplicable).  If I was to write such a function I would probably put `append` somewhere in the name.

Comment: @phils problem with `append` tho is this name does not imply the lists are merged. That is, upon executing `(setq lhs '(1 2)) (append-list-to-list lhs '(3 4))` I would expect `lhs` to become `(1 2 (3 4))` rather than `(1 2 3 4)`. And yes, I don't necessarily read documentation if the name of the method is self-explanatory, such as `print` or `while` or `goto-line`. This ain't "inexplicable", in huge codebases you can't expect every function have docs, especially so given they have tendency to become outdated. The purpose of the function should be clear from its name and type-definition.

Comment: So, I think `merge-list-to-list` might be a better naming, changed to it for now.